# Python Imaplib search multiple SUBJECT criteria and special characters

Tags: python

I have trouble using impalib to search email that contain more than two subjects, for example:

    `import imaplib
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    m.login('myname', 'mypwd')
    m.select("Inbox")
    resp, items = m.uid('search', None, "(SUBJECT baseball SUBJECT basketball)")`

will have no problem getting data from searching those subject. However, if i search more than two subjects

    `resp, items = m.uid('search', None, "(SUBJECT baseball SUBJECT basketball SUBJECT football)")`

it won't have data come back. also, subject like ""space jam" or "matchbox 20" will have trouble of parsing in the field

Answer (score 3):

you can search like this.

`m.uid('search', None, "(OR (SUBJECT baseball) (SUBJECT basketball))")`